# How to use Contextual Actionbar (CAB) with support.v7.widget.Toolbar and Listview?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat, contextual-action-bar

I'm trying to use the CAB with a ListView:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

            mode.setTitle(getString(R.string.list_selector_num_items_selected, listView.getCheckedItemCount()));
            Log.i("LIST",position + " selected");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }
... and so on
```

This creates the CAB with the default ActionBar which is overlaying the Toolbar in combination with this entry in my AppTheme:

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

This is working BUT it look not very nice.

What i would like to achieve is similar to the current Gmail app if you long-press on an email.

Any ideas how to achieve this ?

---

I'm using the SupportActionBar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (toolbar != null) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since everything else is working. I bet it is about styling. You can always style all this.

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
            <!---- other atrributes -->
            <!--- changes the action mode style; height, text size, background etc -->
            <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/MyActionMode</item>
            <!--- changes left icon of that is used to close the action mode -->
            <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_back</item>
    </style>





   <style name="MyActionMode" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionMode">
 <!--- changes background of the container  -->
    <item name="background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
 <!--- changes the action mode background when using actionbar is splitted -->
            <item name="backgroundSplit">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
 <!--- changes height of the actionmode container view -->
            <item name="height">@dimen/toolbar_size</item>
 <!--- changes text style of the title, create your own, this is the default  -->
            <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title</item>
<!--- changes text style of the subtitle, create your own, this is the default  -->
            <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle
            </item>
```

Comment: This is not using the support toolbar. This causes issues when working with drawers and toolbar overlaying stuff. But thank you for answering.